# Sort rows and columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd Dataframe, whose elements are 0 or 1 and each row and column has a label.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100
M = 200
p = 0.8
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (M,N), p=(p, 1-p)),
                  columns=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:N]),
                  index=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:M]))
```

What I would like to do is sorting according to degree (row and column sum) the elements of each block (each label defines a block).

The idea is to use the sum of the rows and columns of each block.
For example, for the first block:

```
df.loc['0', '0'].sum(axis=0)
df.loc['0', '0'].sum(axis=1)
```

and use these values to sort all the rows and columns with label 0

Imagine to have:

```
   0 0 0 1 1 1

0  1 1 1 0 0 1
0  0 0 1 0 0 0
0  1 1 0 0 0 1
1  0 0 0 1 0 0
1  0 0 0 1 1 0
1  0 0 0 1 1 1
```

the desired output is:

```
   0 0 0 1 1 1

0  1 1 1 0 0 1
0  1 1 0 0 0 1
0  1 0 0 0 0 0
1  0 0 0 1 1 1
1  0 0 0 1 1 0
1  0 0 0 1 0 0
```

What matters is the sum of the elements within each block, not of all the line or of the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a starting point that might lead to a more general solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d=  """1 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1"""
    
a = d.split('\n')
a = [r.split(' ') for r in a]

df = pd.DataFrame({column : [int(a[row][column]) for row in range(6)] for column in range(6)})
   
print(df)
print('-' * 10)

df['rsum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['row'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1]
df.sort_values(by=['row', 'rsum'], ascending = [True, False], inplace=True)
df.drop(['rsum', 'row'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
print('-' * 10)
df = df.transpose()
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df['rsum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['row'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1]
df.sort_values(by=['row', 'rsum'], ascending = [True, False], inplace=True)
df.drop(['rsum', 'row'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.transpose()
print(df.values)
```